# Removing the maximize button from a window created using glfw

Tags: c++, winapi, win32-process, glfw

How do you remove the maximize button from a window created usingg the `glfwopenWindow` functionn call ?

Currently, what I'm doing is:

```
windowHandle = GetForegroundWindow();
long Style = GetWindowLong(windowHandle, GWL_STYLE);
Style ^= WS_MAXIMIZEBOX;
SetWindowLong(windowHandle, GWL_STYLE, WS_MAXIMIZEBOX);
```

Where, I get the window handle and then toggle the maximize bit. Then I re-apply the window style. But this doesn't work an it makes the window completely blank without any buttons or title bar. is there anyway to remove the maximize button. I dont want to change the window size whenever the resize function is called

Comment: Screenshot http://i.imgur.com/7LmEU.png

Answer (score 5, accepted):

you code is bugged, as you don't pass back the old style, thus clearing all the style flags except `WS_MAXIMIZEBOX`, it should read:

```
windowHandle = GetForegroundWindow();
long Style = GetWindowLong(windowHandle, GWL_STYLE);
Style &= ~WS_MAXIMIZEBOX; //this makes it still work when WS_MAXIMIZEBOX is actually already toggled off
SetWindowLong(windowHandle, GWL_STYLE, Style);
```

also, you should really use the `GetWindowlongPtr` based functions if you plan on any future x64 compatability

Comment: +1 for GetWindowlongPtr mentioning. I always prefer to make my code portable across platform though I won't do it.

Comment: Don't use `GetForegroundWindow`, because there's no guarantee that your window is the foreground window. Wouldn't it be sad if your program accidentally removed the MAXIMIZE button from Task Manager? Presumably you already know your window handle; just use it directly. (At least switch to `GetActiveWindow`, which will get the active window for your thread.)

Comment: @raymond: you should be commenting on the OP's question, seeing thats his code, but you are 100% right