# Removing the minimize and maximize buttons with glfw

Tags: java, cross-platform, lwjgl, glfw

I'm using glfw 3.2 with LWJGL and Java.

I'd like to remove the maximize, and minimize button on my windows while the window remains resizable, and I can't find any way to do that in the glfw documentation.

I've seen [this solution](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8034053/removing-the-maximize-button-from-a-window-created-using-glfw) but it only works on windows, and with C++, the solution I'm looking for needs to be cross platform.

Is it possible to achieve this using glfw? Or should I use an undecorated glfw window and draw my own title bar?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no way of achieving that with GLFW 3.2